# Is there a way to to identify the latest non null value in a window frame in BIGQUERY?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I was hoping I could get some help on identifying the latest non-null value in a window frame ordered by date in BigQuery. I had some tries until now with first_value and partitions but no luck.

Input:

| Date | Key | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-13 | 1 | In Progress |
| 2021-01-13 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-14 | 1 | Waiting |
| 2021-01-14 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-01-15 | 1 | NULL |
| 2021-01-15 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-01-16 | 1 | NULL |
| 2021-01-16 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-01-17 | 1 | In Progress |
| 2021-01-17 | 2 | NULL |
| 2021-01-18 | 1 | NULL |
| 2021-01-18 | 2 | NULL |

The expected output is:

| Date | Key | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-13 | 1 | In Progress |
| 2021-01-13 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-14 | 1 | Waiting |
| 2021-01-14 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-15 | 1 | Waiting |
| 2021-01-15 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-16 | 1 | Waiting |
| 2021-01-16 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-17 | 1 | In Progress |
| 2021-01-17 | 2 | Closed |
| 2021-01-18 | 1 | In Progress |
| 2021-01-18 | 2 | Closed |

Hopefully, I have included the relevant information.
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(status),
  last_value(status ignore nulls) over(partition by key order by date) as status
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]